# Granting access to user specific images in an s3 private bucket through app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mean-stack

I have a MEAN stack app built where the user can upload images. Currently, I'm storing the URLs of the images in mongodb, and the images themselves in the filesystem in a specified folder. I've read that it's better to store these images somewhere like AWS or firebase for scalability, so I decided to go with AWS.

I created a bucket and can upload images fine via multer.

How can I allow users to only retrieve their images when they are logged into my app? The authentication in the frontend and backend is already finished, but I can't figure out how to use this with accessing the s3 bucket and only getting the user specific images.

I could make the bucket public and easily build the URLs, but that means everyone (regardless if they are logged into my app or not) can access them, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you can authenticate your users as [Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) users then during a login they will assume a role.

If that role has a policy attached for S3 you can use the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` variable. By structuring your S3 bucket to use key paths containing this variable in it you can develop a policy that will only grant access to keys with the prefix of that user id.

Take a look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html) for an example S3 policy.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still needed.
You already have authentication built, so use that.
Check if your user is already logged in and if they have access to the image they are requesting, after you make sure they have proper access then create a pre-signed URL, and return that URL to the user.

Pre-signed URLs are unique, and only valid for a certain period of time.

[More Info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)